# Java - ServerSocket without port-forward

Tags: java, port, forward

I'm making a Java application that involves every user hosting a small server. This allows the other clients to, with each others IPs check what they're doing.

But of course this needs port-forwarding to work, which people often have trouble with.

So, is there a way to work without port-forwarding, while still having a full-performance connection?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why does having multiple users means having more than one server? How does this allow other clients to check anything and why is this desirable? Why is port forwarding needed?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you (OP) refer to individual user's firewall/router port forwarding? If yes, than with your setup - every user running individual server - the problem is unavoidable. Alternative setup is suggested by "wollud1969" in his answer bellow.   
Or did you mean something else?

Comment: The idea is that every client hosts a Server. When a client starts up, it tells certain servers (if they're up) that it's online. So we need a ServerSocket that won't need portforwarding.

Answer (score 0):

What about a central server with a direct connection or a valid port forwardning configuration to which the users open a connection which is user as a kind of a tunnel.

Comment: Thats exactly why each client hosts it's own small background Server - to avoid this method.

Comment: I fear, then you have no option to get around port-forwarding. But wait, do you know about UPNP?

Comment: That is a protocol for the communication between devices and the router in a home setup, allowing the device to request a port-forwarding at the router. However, it can be disabled on the router and security concerned Users will disable it.

Comment: Sounds good, do you know any good tutorials for implementing it?

Comment: I never used it - since, to be honest, I consider it as evil (I don't want any software configuring around on my router/firewall) - but maybe you find something useful here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp#References